# How can I fetch scientific name using common name in R?

Tags: r

E.g.
`get_scientific_name("avacado")` should result in `c("Persea americana")`.
Some of the relevant packages that I came across was [rgbif](https://docs.ropensci.org/rgbif/) and `[taxize][2]` ?

Specifically I am interested in names of crops.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a little wrapper to parse the results from `pow_search` in the `taxize` package:

```r
get_scientific_name <- function(name) {
  taxize::pow_search(name)$data$name[1]
}
```

Testing on the common name of several crops seems to give sensible results:

```
get_scientific_name('avocado')
#> [1] "Persea americana"

get_scientific_name('sweetcorn')
#> [1] "Zea mays"

get_scientific_name('carrot')
#> [1] "Daucus carota"

get_scientific_name('spelt')
#> [1] "Triticum spelta"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. I found another way using `taxize` that I have added as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Allan Cameron's answer, [taxize](https://docs.ropensci.org/taxize/reference/comm2sci.html) package has functions to get the scientific names based on common names.

```
taxize::comm2sci("avocado")
```

returns

```
$avocado
[1] "Persea americana"
```